# Referencing App in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am having an issue when running my ember-cli app in production mode. When I reference `App.deferReadiness()` it is acting as if App is undefined.

app/app.coffee

```coffeescript
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import Resolver from 'ember/resolver'`
`import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers'`
`import config from './config/environment'`

App = Ember.Application.extend
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix
  Resolver: Resolver
  ready: ->
    Ember.debug "Total setup time: #{(new Date).valueOf() - startTime.valueOf()}ms"

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix)

`export default App`
```

app/initializers/facebook.coffee

```coffeescript
`import App from 'my_app/app'`
initialize = (container, application) ->
  # Results in: t.default.deferReadiness is not a function
  App.deferReadiness()
  # omitted code
```

This works fine in development mode, but something is up in production. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that this was a bad example as `application` is the second argument in facebook.coffee initialize. When/if I come up with a better example, I'll update my question.

Comment: Are you by chance accessing App using the same name as it's global name? E.g. if you've got your app open and you go to the console and type 'MyApp' it will give you a global variable that is your apps instance - when you move to production this is no longer available since everything is minified/compressed and it either turns into a one letter global variable or it's possible the Ember code doesn't make it available at all in the production build.. I've just tried to export App from 'my_app/app' and it doesn't have the deferReadiness function at all - and its also a class not an instance..

Comment: @jmurphyau that is what I discovered as well. I solved my problem another way. I removed all references to `App`. The areas that were encountering the issue were in initializers. When defining an initializer two arguments are give to the initializer `container` and `application`. That was all I really needed. Once I started using those, I was able to get rid of all the `App` references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to determine why there was a difference between development mode and production, but I was able to find a way to work around the issue. All of the places I was referring to `App` were in initializers. Initializers receive the arguments `container` and `application`. By using these arguments, I was able to stop using `App`. There was one more reference to `App.__container__.lookup` in a controller (I know nasty). This was easy to fix with `this.container.lookup`. I believe these changes resolve my issue.